# Powershell equivalent of "dir /a"?

Tags: windows, powershell, dir, directory-listing

Running `dir /a` on a given directory on one of our servers produces a list of unexpected files that look like malware:

```
C:\Users\<username>dir /a c:\Users\Public\Downloads\
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9999-9999

 Directory of c:\Users\Public\Downloads

09/15/2018  12:19 AM    <DIR>          .
09/15/2018  12:19 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/09/2023  09:28 PM            20,000 ZZZZZ2852017353.doc
07/21/2023  10:10 PM            50,240 !!!!!2729304900.doc
07/21/2023  09:34 PM         3,000,000 XORXOR2654977376.doc
07/21/2023  09:53 PM             1,024 smTlX4069337007.txt
07/09/2023  09:22 PM             2,024 ZZZZZ2452917832.docx
07/17/2023  08:59 PM             4,048 !!!!!910538317.pem
06/27/2023  08:58 PM            10,000 XORXOR2801197100.jpg
07/21/2023  08:27 PM            20,000 smTlX1631532574.png
07/21/2023  08:42 PM            25,000 ZZZZZ2426080075.bmp
07/21/2023  08:44 PM            30,000 !!!!!503919568.eml
07/09/2023  08:58 PM           100,000 XORXOR2564426092.xls
06/27/2023  08:53 PM           150,000 smTlX2350243133.xlsx
07/17/2023  09:41 PM           175,000 ZZZZZ3070700973.mdb
07/21/2023  09:53 PM           200,000 !!!!!533403438.ppt
07/21/2023  09:04 PM           225,000 XORXOR395504056.pps
07/09/2023  08:50 PM           250,000 smTlX634944309.pptx
07/09/2023  09:13 PM           275,000 ZZZZZ2775334046.pdf
06/27/2023  08:26 PM           300,000 !!!!!3608986092.avi
06/27/2023  08:56 PM           350,000 XORXOR189161240.db
06/27/2023  09:53 PM           350,000 smTlX416169661.pst
06/27/2023  09:54 PM           400,000 ZZZZZ2740091908.sql
07/21/2023  10:12 PM    <DIR>          !!!!!1300245113
09/15/2018  12:16 AM               174 desktop.ini
07/09/2023  09:28 PM            20,000 ZZZZZ3219714798.doc
07/21/2023  10:10 PM            50,240 !!!!!4004685157.doc
07/21/2023  09:34 PM         3,000,000 XORXOR3352709303.doc
07/21/2023  09:53 PM             1,024 smTlX3205606753.txt
07/09/2023  09:22 PM             2,024 ZZZZZ331100468.docx
07/17/2023  08:59 PM             4,048 !!!!!1274788081.pem
06/27/2023  08:58 PM            10,000 XORXOR647044953.jpg
07/21/2023  08:27 PM            20,000 smTlX1871256990.png
07/21/2023  08:42 PM            25,000 ZZZZZ638203430.bmp
07/21/2023  08:44 PM            30,000 !!!!!4241961912.eml
07/09/2023  08:58 PM           100,000 XORXOR1411632423.xls
06/27/2023  08:53 PM           150,000 smTlX743786790.xlsx
07/17/2023  09:41 PM           175,000 ZZZZZ4216568629.mdb
07/21/2023  09:53 PM           200,000 !!!!!2025383911.ppt
07/21/2023  09:04 PM           225,000 XORXOR1743807666.pps
07/09/2023  08:50 PM           250,000 smTlX229377095.pptx
07/09/2023  09:13 PM           275,000 ZZZZZ191670683.pdf
06/27/2023  08:26 PM           300,000 !!!!!1941248879.avi
06/27/2023  08:56 PM           350,000 XORXOR1946193784.db
06/27/2023  09:53 PM           350,000 smTlX2089358877.pst
06/27/2023  09:54 PM           400,000 ZZZZZ249794861.sql
07/21/2023  10:12 PM    <DIR>          !!!!!157789779
              43 File(s)     11,874,846 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  82,072,215,552 bytes free
```

Whether I run `Command Prompt` "as administrator" or not - does not matter, the result is the same.

While the malware itself is a separate issue, I'd like to produce a similar list in Powershell so I could try to to automate scanning for these and similar files across multiple machines.

Yet when I run `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\" -Force` on the same server (as suggested elsewhere on SO e.g. in "[How to list all files in a folder (do cmd's `dir /A`) in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859219/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-folder-do-cmds-dir-a-in-powershell)"), I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\<username>> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\" -Force


    Directory: C:\Users\Public\Downloads


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-        9/15/2018  12:16 AM            174 desktop.ini
```

Running the above "as administrator" - same result.

... which begs the title question:

What is the Powershell equivalent of "dir /a"?

P.S.

- I can't get the files in question to display in File Explorer - even after I enable hidden and system files
- It's Windows Server 2019. Its `C:\` drive is growing linearly at about ~95GB a month. The total disk space used (320GB) doesn't seem to add up when checking all root directories' sizes individually (100-150GB). I have a feeling these files may be the culprit.

Comment: Are you allowed to download and compile from source code [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) and [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)? They probably have been ported to Windows

Comment: probably not - and then there's a question of whether compiled tools would expose information that built-in ones (Powershell) would not. The question is specific to Powershell.

Comment: This is better asked on [SU] or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: You'd be right if the question was about malware... it's not. The title question is really about Powershell. Similar questions where allowed to stay on SO.

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, you can run `cmd /c dir /a` from PowerShell.

Comment: good point - I can - except this isn't really an *equivalent* (of `dir /a`) - just a way to run the same command, and thus does not answer the title question. The good news is that I could parse the output, fish out the filenames (which then *can* be examined by e.g. `Get-Item`) - i.e. this could allow to automate scanning and collecting stats on those files and doing something with them (e.g. deleting) - even if it's cumbersome AF.

Comment: Yes, they are Palo Alto [Cortex XDR decoys](https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/cortex-xdr-discussions/strange-files-malware/m-p/552454) - thanks! - we still need a good handle on these, ideally using Powershell. (The fact that I see next to nothing in Cortex XDR console about these, and they seem to be in every one of the gazillions of directories on the server means something went wrong with these - and we need to automate their detection across all of our servers.)

Comment: You can probably already get the files to show by running `get-childitem -hidden` Its not the same as `dir /a` though, but for your usecase it is probably enough.

Comment: Also, you could technically do `cmd.exe /c dir /a /b |foreach-object {write-host "File: $pwd\$_" -foregroundcolor yellow}` or `cmd.exe /c dir /a /b /s |foreach-object {write-host "File: $_" -foregroundcolor yellow}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if `dir /A` outputs **all** files as documentation specifies, but if it does, you can do the same this way in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes ([System.IO.FileAttributes].GetEnumValues() -Join ",") -Force
```

Explantation:

- [`System.IO.FileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-7.0) is an `Enum` that contains all possible values for file/directory attributes
- we get an array of the values with `GetEnumValues()` and join them as strings with `,` character, which means `OR` in the [`-Attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-attributes) parameter value
- then also `-Force` is used just in case, but it might be not needed

To optimize a script, you could of course also get the attributes value in PowerShell shell and paste it as a long string instead.

Comment: It does. `Dir /a` will list all files that have at least one attribute set, so if you do `attrib -a +h` on a file, `get-childitem` will not find it, but `dir /a` does. If a file does not have the hidden attribute set, `get-childitem` will return it too. I bet `get-childitem -hidden` is already enough here

Comment: Thank you! Can't yet test as the files are gone as of this morning - likely Palo Alto support cleaning them up. Not yet sure how to reproduce this (the files were not just "hidden" or "system" - they appeared to be links pointing to actual hidden files in a different (hidden, as well) directory, and I haven't gotten to trying to reproducing this scenario.)

Comment: I'm, pretty sure `GCI -Hidden` wouldn't show system files at the very least, which might not be necessary here, but the question asks about equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory,Hidden,System,ReparsePoint,ReadOnly,Archive,NotContentIndexed,Offline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, will test it tomorrow (hopefully)

Comment: Can't yet test as the files are gone as of this morning - likely Palo Alto support cleaning them up. Not yet sure how to reproduce this (the files were not just "hidden" or "system" - they appeared to be links pointing to actual hidden files in a different (hidden, as well) directory, and I haven't gotten to trying to reproducing this scenario.)